# Go RWMutex still raises race condition?

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, race-condition

I have a seemingly innocent package that just makes a slice and protects it with a RWMutex. However, when I run it, it still complains about a race condition. What am I doing wrong? ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/peZtmrp0A6T))

```
type Ids struct {
    e []int64
    sync.RWMutex
}

func (i *Ids) Read() []int64 {
    i.RLock()
    defer i.RUnlock()

    return i.e
}


func (i *Ids) Append(int int64) {
    i.Lock()
    defer i.Unlock()

    i.e = append(i.e, int)
}

func main() {
    t := &Ids{e: make([]int64, 1)}

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", t.Read())
        }()

        go func() {
            t.Append(int64(i))
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}
```

when run with `-race`, it returns (among other things):

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c4200a0010 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func2()
      .../main.go:38 +0x38

Previous write at 0x00c4200a0010 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      .../main.go:32 +0x197

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      .../main.go:37 +0x173
==================
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are capturing the same variable `i` in multiple goroutines.

One way to fix this is to modify your main for loop like so:

```
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    i := i  # look here
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", t.Read())
    }()

    go func() {
        t.Append(int64(i))
    }()
}
```

This will ensure that you capture a different variable in the closure of the second goroutine each iteration of the for loop. In your example, the `i` passed to `t.Append` was the same `i` that was incremented by the for loop concurrently.

I also recommend running `go vet` to catch such errors in the future. For more information, there is an entry on this problem in the Go FAQ that goes into more detail: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: Can second the `go vet` recommendation, `gometalinter` is pretty useful as well. Another popular way to fix it is to pass `i` as an argument to the `go func`.